# Python Google Stackdriver Snapshots in dependencies

Tags: google-app-engine, debugging, python-3.7, stackdriver

My app is deployed on the python 3.7 Google App Engine standard environment. It has a bug that causes it to silently fail when a certain library function gets called. I'd like to set some log points inside the library function, but I'm not seeing a way to do that. Is it possible to set log points inside external dependencies using Stackdriver? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Stackdriver debugger](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/quickstart). It allows you to  inspect the state of an application, at any code location, without stopping or slowing down the running app and you can configure your Python application to use [Stackdriver Debugger](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/python).

Also [Stackdriver Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/overview) is a distributed tracing system that collects latency data from your applications and displays it in the Google Cloud Platform Console.

Comment: I've already configured my app to use Stackdriver. I'm only able to look at the code I deployed though, not the dependencies included via `requirements.txt`. The app dies inside one of my dependencies but I can't tell where because I can't find a way to set log points inside a dependency.